# Recommended way to load data from SQL and convert it into Binary

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, mtom

I have data on a SQL Server 2008 database and need to load it and send it via a WCF web service based on the MTOM encoding.

**QUESTION 1:**
I wonder if I need to prepare and compress the `DataTable` (or whatever I will load from SQL Server) into binary form or just because it's MTOM, the process will automatically do the compression?

**QUESTION 2:**
What is the best way to load and prepare the data it for WCF?
I could use Linq-to-SQL, EF4 ...or any other suggested method to load the data.

I'm using C#

Thanks.

Comment: What is "the data" here? you mention DataTable, then "or whatever I will load from the SQL" - there's a huge difference. Why does it need to be binary? (don't misunderstand me: I'm a huge fan of binary over things like WCF - but I'd like to know that it is solving the right problem; so what is the specific reason you want to use binary?). Note that **by default**, MTOM will try to spot BLOBs (`byte[]` etc) in existing `[DataContract]` types), and will try to hoist it out. Do you **have** BLOBs? or are you looking to reduce overall bandwidth? or...?

Comment: As for question 2: WCF doesn't care how you load your data - it just transmits data. From a WCF point of view : any method will be fine. WCF doesn't "prefer" any particular way, nor does it work "better" with some method or another. You're absolutely free to choose....

Comment: @Marc I have SQL tables, so i just guessed those tables will be loaded into DataTable, but maybe that's not the case. I am free to choose whatever approach I prefer. I do NOT have any Blobs fields on the tables.

For Question 2, maybe the right question is ..what is the preferred way to load data and make it as small as possible so that WCF has less data to transmit

Comment: OK, that makes more sense for question #2: my recommendation would be to use as simple a method as possible - don't use DataTable or other abstractions - those have too much overhead. Use simple objects, and lists of objects that you fetch from the database using e.g. a `SqlDataReader`

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Framework Self Tracking Entities.
Once you generate the model it will generate a separate file for data access logic and separate file with the model, already prepared for WCF(with contract attributes).

Comment: Are those models optimized for WCF, meaning that will the resulting container of those tables will be optimized to be sent over WCF?

Some tables might contain 1000s of records ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "optimized to be sent over WCF", but the point of self-tracking entities is for N-tier applications with WCF as the communication layer between the tiers. So yes, as far as I can tell, it's specifically optimized to work with WCF. On the other hand - no matter how you send thousands of records - it still might take time, depending on the size of the records and your bandwidth.